# How to apply Superset Migrations when running in docker mode?

Tags: apache-superset

Currently I'm running Superset in Docker mode. No native installation. The metadata database is an external(non-docker) Postgres DB which has lots of Dashboards, Charts etc.

Current installation is running on `git tag 1.0.0`. I want to upgrade to `v1.1.0`. I can do this by switching the repo to `git tag 1.1.0` and restarting docker containers.

However as per `UPDATING.md` notes, `v1.1.0` has a [DB migration](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/1.1.0/UPDATING.md) .

In native installation, the way to migrate DB is `superset db upgrade`

What's the proper method to apply these migration scripts to an existing external database in docker installation?

Answer (score 1):

Lauch you stack if done with compose it will run automaticly the db upgrade command.

if not `docker exec -it <supersetcontainerID> /bin/bash`

Just ensure to have the correct sqlalchemy chain on the superset config file.

And then fire the `superset db upgrade`

You're done.

Answer (score 0):

First, chekout your container id ,then use below command to backup superset.db

```
docker cp 1263b3cdf7e7:/root/.superset/superset.db
```

Then after the upgrade,you can just simple cp and replace superset.db back into your new version